# What can I do with the FileManager of Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2

I am reading the source of Struts2, and I found when the Dispatcher is initialized, it will init FileManager. It looks like be used to monitor files, but I don't know how to use it to monitor file.

```
   try {
        ***init_FileManager();***
        init_DefaultProperties(); // [1]
        init_TraditionalXmlConfigurations(); // [2]
        init_LegacyStrutsProperties(); // [3]
        init_CustomConfigurationProviders(); // [5]
        init_FilterInitParameters() ; // [6]
        init_AliasStandardObjects() ; // [7]

        Container container = init_PreloadConfiguration();
        container.inject(this);
        init_CheckWebLogicWorkaround(container);

        if (!dispatcherListeners.isEmpty()) {
            for (DispatcherListener l : dispatcherListeners) {
                l.dispatcherInitialized(this);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (LOG.isErrorEnabled())
            LOG.error("Dispatcher initialization failed", ex);
        throw new StrutsException(ex);
    }
```

Can someone tells me?
Many thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: It's used internally to monitor files which have to be reloaded (in devMode) - mostly JBoss is an issue as it uses Virtual File System which isn't a normal file system and uses strange mechanism to handle files (or nodes)